# How can I do a method that return the Color that is more times repeated?

Tags: java, count

Is something like:

```
public Color colorMoreTimesRepeated()
{    


}
```

and I don't know how to make a variable that count the different colors and return me the one that is repeated more times.

The idea is to count all the colors of an image and give the color that is repeated more times, I have tried using *2 journeys with for and when a anycolor is repeated it begins to count and at the end it return the one that is more repeated.

```
   *for(int i=0;i< high;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<wide;j++){*
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do you actually want? Read your question and try to think if it is understandable to anyone but yourself.

Comment: How do you define colors? is it Color.WHITE etc. or is it colors that have all kinds of rgb values?

Comment: all of rgb valuesthat you can find in  a image

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you want to identify the color that is filling maximum number of pixels in a given image.

If I am right, you can use the following method!

```
private static Color getColorOccuringMaxTimesInImage(File imageFile) throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    Map<Integer, Integer> colors = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int maxCount = 0;
    Integer maxColor = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            Integer color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            Integer count = colors.get(color);
            if (count == null)
                count = 0;

            Integer next = count + 1;
            colors.put(color, next);

            if (next > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = next;
                maxColor = color;
            }
        }
    }

    return new Color(maxColor.intValue());
}
```